# BigDecimal as a parameter of REST API

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, bigdecimal

such a simple question,

Can a `BigDecimal` field used as a parameter for a REST API in my WebObject?

As `BigDecimal` should be instantiated using constructor, will that happen if I send the parameter

```
{
    "input" : 5
}
```

Will this parameter instantiated to BigDecimal automatically?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends as what API framework you using. With Spring Boot which uses Jackson API to deserialize, this will be converted correctly.

Directly using `BigDecimal` in front transfer object might not give you correct scaling & precision so I recommend to take `String` input and customize your `BigDecimal` creation as per need.